# Selecting a field error in Test Class

Tags: unit-test

I created a batch that selects many fields in the start method. Here's an exemple of the hierarchy

- Field called SelectedFieldX__c in the object LookupObjectX__c (I used
  it in the execute method)
- Field called OtherFieldX__c in the object    LookupObjectX__c (I used
  it in the execute method)
- Field called    FieldX__c in the object ChildObjectX__c, it is a
  lookup field of the    LookupObjectX__c object
- Fields FieldX1__c,    FieldX2__c in the object    ChildObjectX__c The
  ChildObjectX__c    object is a child of the object 
  ParentObjectX__c.

Here's an example of the query:

```
Select Id, (Select Id, FieldX__c, FieldX__r.SelectedFieldX__c, FieldX__r.OtherFieldX__c, FieldX1__c, FieldX2__c From ChildObjectX__r) From ParentObjectX__c
```

When I executed the test class I had this error :`"SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field : SelectedFieldX__c"`, knowing that I selected it in the query, and it contains a value in Salesforce. In addition, when I debugged the result of the query I had this value.

When I used it in the code like this exemple :

```
Set<String> selectedValues = new Set<String>();
for(ParentObjectX__c parentObj : scopeList){
    System.Debug('Debugging 1 ' + parentObj.ChildObjectX__r);
    for(ChildObjectX__c childObj : parentObj.ChildObjectX__r){
        selectedValues.add(childObj.FieldX__r.SelectedFieldX__c);
    }
}
```

The Debugging 1 contains these values : Id, FieldX__r.OtherFieldX__c only and I got the error mentioned above.

Comment: Suggest you clean up the formatting (if you have rights to do that)  by editing the question and using the various formatting buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was from security of the field, The actual profile doesn't have the rights on this field, so when I gave it the right, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just write your query like this:

```
Select Id, SelectedFieldX__c, OtherFieldX__c, (Select Id, FieldX__c, FieldX__r.SelectedFieldX__c, FieldX__r.OtherFieldX__c, FieldX1__c, FieldX2__c From ChildObjectX__r) From ParentObjectX__c
```

Comment: Hi Patlatus, thank you but the field SelectedFieldX__c is not a field for the ParentObjectX__c, so if I put this it will generate another error